# How to display a message along with the time in groupchat?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application in that, I have an group chat functionality when i am send a message on group chat i need to display message along with the time(at the end of the message the time need to display on every chat message).

```
Here is my layout code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lightred"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

"@+id/txtInfo" used for get the current date and time & "@+id/txtMsg" used for display the message.

now my output is looking like this
[image]

but i am expecting my output as,
[image]

my programming code is below,

```
 public class MessagesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private List<ChatMessageObjects> messagesItems;

        public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, List<ChatMessageObjects> navDrawerItems) {
            this.context = context;
            this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return messagesItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return messagesItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            /**
             * The following list not implemented reusable list items as list items
             * are showing incorrect data Add the solution if you have one
             * */

            ChatMessageObjects m = messagesItems.get(position);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (messagesItems.get(position).getMessage_type() == Constants.IS_TYPE_CHAT_IMAGE) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_image,
                        null);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                TextView imageLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblImage);
                if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 0) {
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, " the value is from others");
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(messagesItems.get(position).getMessage());
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                } else if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 1) {
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, " the value is itself");
                    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
                    imageLabel.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getFromName());
                }
            } else if (messagesItems.get(position).getMessage_type() == Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_MSG) {
                if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 1) {
                    // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_right,
                            null);
                    TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                    //date and time added here
                    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                    txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());
                    lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());
                    date.setText(m.getDate());
                } else if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 0) {
                    // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_left,
                            null);
                    TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                    //date and time added here
                    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                    txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());
                    lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());
                    date.setText(m.getDate());
                }

            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

date.setText(m.getDate()); code get my date in this format"28-aug-2015 11:46:11pm". I need to convert my date in this format"11:46 pm" how can i change this format and how to display chat message along with time as looking above please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your **LinearLayout orientation** from "**vertical**" to "**horizontal**".

You can use Time to represent hours and minutes, like this:

```
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();
    String timeInput = today.hour + ":" + today.minute;
```

Better approach is to use SimpleDateFormat:

```
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
    String msgTime = s.format(new Date());
```

**EDIT**:

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
String msgTime = today.format("HH:mm a")
```

Use this example to show formatted Time.

Comment: The time is working fine can you please add code for mentioned the current time is am/pm(i.e "12:30 pm")

Comment: i am using your first date format can you say how to displayed time with am/pm on that ...

Comment: can you please suggest the code changes for get my expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Formmating the date can be done like this:
Declare a `SimpleDateFormat` object with the desired format -

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");`. You can set the format string as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Then you can get a `string` to hold your time - `String myTime = sdf.format(new Date());` and add that string to your message.

EDIT -
For time format of 12:30 am/pm you should use `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");`.

Comment: it works fine can you please say how to mentioned time with am/pm(i.e "12:30 pm")

Comment: sure - "h:mm a". It's all in the link in my answer.

Comment: yeah it working fine again thanks for your response.

Comment: You forgot to mention how to change the layout orientation

Comment: yeah layout oreintation is changed but the time is still  displayed outside of message horizontally. can i am changing anything else of above layout code to get my expected output

Comment: I think that the `GRAVITY` of `txtInfo` should be right, not left.

Comment: the layout orientation is changed from vertical to horizontal by using that the layout orientation get changed.

Comment: You did not specify any gravity for your txtMsg in your XML. Experiment with layout_gravity and gravity for both elements and you will find the way around.